# make 'srm' the default command instead 'rm' in linux

Tags: linux

I want force users to use 'srm' instead of 'rm' command. is there any solution to execute 'srm' command when users run rm command? or deny users permissions to run 'rm'?

Answer (score 4):

Just create an alias:

alias rm='srm'

You can put this command in the .bashrc file for the user you have to keep under control, so that it is automatically loaded at login.

You can also put it into /etc/bashrc, so that it's loaded for ALL the users.

Comment: Yep, this is a good answer. you could also put it in ~/.profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases to do this. 
Create an alias as ,

> alais rm="srm"

Add this in to the bash_profile or bashrc file or even better create a bash_alias file that will be called from bashrc file.

For a general intro on Aliases, refer this http://bit.do/freblogg-aliases